# Can we put lockMode=LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in JPA delete query?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have written a named query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "deleteEmployee", query = "DELETE from emp e where e.Id = :Id", lockMode=LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
```

However Eclipse link throws following error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  A lock type can only be used with a select query (which allows the database to be locked where necessary)
```

However it works with openJPA, and I didnt see any java docs related to above exception. Please suggest.

Comment: makes little sense using it, since a lock is to keep it locked until some later time. Yet if you are deleting something then it is deleted in that one statement.